# Telegram bot- add to a private chat between two human beings

Tags: telegram-bot

Say my friend and I are talking in a "regular chat" (no groups) and I want to invoke a bot there for some help. Now I know about the existence of inline bots which would only see what is written after `@mylinebot` in a message, but I wonder if there is a way to add a bot to our private chat which once invoked can listen to everything we say?

For example:

```
Me: hi friend

friend: hi me

me: @myfavbot can you suggest a color

myfavbot: green

friend: green not good

myfavbot: ok blue # Notice how myfavbot was able to listen to my friend talking
```

Currently after I invoke `myfavbot`, I don't get anything in the `getUpdates` API call.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't add a bot to your private chat, But I suggest use tdlib to create a bot. tdlib actually is not for creating a telegram bot. It's a library you can easily create a telegram client app. So it can create another session to your account and has access to everything you have.

Comment: Thanks for the `tdlib` suggestion, I would look into it. 

@ others- please up/down vote if you find MrMoeinM's answer correct (ie NO way to add a bot to priv chat)